# Zxing library barcode scan pauses or shows black screen sometimes

Tags: android, tabs, android-viewpager, zxing

I am using zxing library to scan a barcode , I have scanner at 2 places(2 tabs) in my app. I am using Tablayout with viewpager to host tabs.

I am getting different devices.
On nexus 6 (os version 6.1)

when i click on 2nd tab, scanner camera works fine on 2nd tab, but then i again click on 1st tab scanning feature works fine on 1st tab , now when i click on 2nd tab again, Scaner camera pauses at its previous state.

On moto g2 (Os 5.0.2)
scanner camera works fine on first click of tab but it turns black when that particular tab is selected again.

I have attached images for better understanding.

image with scan button on home tab will lead to the screen with heading Scan1
and second tab is with camera icon that is with heading Scan

[image: home page with tabs and scan button]

[image: scan feature from second tab]

[image: scan feature from scan button in home tab]

Comment: Hi Saawan, I'm having similar issue, were you able to resolve it? I would really appreciate, if you can help me out, I also posted my code and question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43075684/xamarin-android-zxing-black-screen-unable-to-scan-barcode

Comment: Hello @TheDeveloper I had to replace the library. Sorry for the late reply

Answer (score 0):

Zxing scanner unfortunately does not work like that.  To make it work you should only have one instance of the scanner.  If you want to use it in multiple tabs, its best to reuse the same View for the two tabs.  When onPageChanged gets called, you can replace the view with the one instance Zxing view.

Comment: Hi, can you help me out I have similar question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43075684/xamarin-android-zxing-black-screen-unable-to-scan-barcode